# Mac Notes App Sync Containers Having Mac Applications

Tags: macos, notes.app

[image: Inside ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/]

[image: Two Open With Applications]

I saw same two applications under "open with" menu and searching for the other instance took me to ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/Media folder.

After backing up notes, I deleted the Macvim.app from the notes media folder but the moment I open the notes app it reappeared. I'm not sure how to clean up and there are other apps also inside the folder such as Dashboard.app and Firefox.app.

Please advise if anyone has encountered this issue or has resolved it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow icloud had backup data of old notes plus apps. So after backing my current notes, I deleted the backed up data from icloud. After resyncing the notes, the problem was fixed.[image]